# Перенаправить входящие соединения на VPN

Tags: openvpn

На сервере Ubuntu поднял свой OpenVPN, подключился через ПК.
Задача стоит в том: как перенаправлять любое входящее соединение на порту 8081 клиенту в сети VPN?

Comment: Что попытались сделать самостоятельно в этом направлении?